# Stack overflow issue while converting into JSON

Tags: java, thread-safety, fasterxml

Here is my code snippet. I have to make parallel calls using ForkJoin but my throws stack overflow without even reaching the service call.

Request:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Request{

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id;

    public Request id(String id){
      this.id=id;
      return this;
    }

    public static Request getRequest(AnotherRequest anotherReq){
        return new Request().id(anotherReq.identity);
    }

    public String getJson() throws Exception {
     return new ObjectMapper().writeValueasString(this);
    }

}
```

MyCallable:

```
@AllargsConstructor
MyCallable implements Callable<Response> {
  private Service service;
  private Request request;
  public Response call () throws Exception{
     return service.callWebservice(this.request.getJson());
  }

}
```

main method :

```
@Autowired
private Service service;
List<MyCallable> jobs = new ArrayList<MyCallable>()
anotherRequestSS.forEach(anotherRequest->{
  jobs.add(new MyCallable(Request.getRequest(anotherRequest),service);
}

ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

pool.invokeAll(jobs);
```

This code goes into infinite loop, meaning `getJson` is called infinite times causing a stack overflow. It does not even reach to the point of `invokeAll()`. What could be the cause of this?

List size `anotherRequestSS` is 2.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that fasterxml interprets the method "getJson()" as a property that it has to include into the generated JSON.

Rewrite your class as

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Request{

  @JsonProperty("id")
  private String id;

  public Request id(String id){
    this.id=id;
    return this;
  }

  public static Request getRequest(AnotherRequest anotherReq){
    return new Request().id(anotherReq.identity);
  }

  public String asJson() throws Exception {
    return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(this);
  }
}
```

and your MyCallable correspondingly

```
@AllargsConstructor
MyCallable implements Callable<Response> {
  private Service service;
  private Request request;
  public Response call () throws Exception{
     return service.callWebservice(this.request.asJson());
  }
}
```